# Set opportunity amount to match custom field

Tags: trigger, opportunity

I am trying to set the amount field to match a custom "Formula (Currency) field "Total_Amount_Initial_Fees__c"  every time I try to save it i get the error :

> Compile Error: Variable does not exist: Total_Amount_Initial_Fees__c
>   at line 3 column 6

```
trigger Update_amount on Opportunity (after insert) {
  for (opportunity obj: trigger.new){
     Total_Amount_Initial_Fees__c = amount;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify what variable the field is on. Just add obj. on the front.

```
trigger Update_amount on Opportunity (after insert) { 
  for (opportunity obj: trigger.new){ 
    obj.Amount = Total_Amount_Initial_Fees__c; 
  } 
}
```

Note, that you could do this with a workflow rule and a field update instead. Always better to go with config before resorting to code.

Comment: Hey @Daniel..no doubt you have corrected the syntax of the code. But i noticed that your code too may give following error
Compile Error: Field is not writeable: Opportunity.Total_Amount_Initial_Fees__c as its a formula field as mentioned

Comment: fields should probably be just the other way around then

Comment: That fixed the first error but now I get another error when making a new OPP. Maybe I need to do this on the OPP product level ? Initial_fees_c + Price = sales price I am not sure how to start this any help would be great

Comment: Oops, helps to read the question a little more closely! I fixed the answer.